# Editing Web Part Page removes all content

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a web part page using the built in ones available, then I opened it in SP designer 2013 and added a some web part zones.

I then added web parts to the page in browser but decided I needed another zone, so I opened the page in SP designer 2013 again and added the zone but all the content I added to the page in the browser disappeared, is there away to stop this from happening?

Thanks